# Why can't the type of my class-static auto function be deduced within the class scope?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to get the return type of an `auto` function. [This works](https://godbolt.org/g/w0lNFA):

```
auto foo(int bar)
{
    return 0;
}

typedef std::result_of<decltype(foo)> foo_t;
```

Great, here's the next step then: getting the return type of a `static auto` function in a class scope. [This also works](https://godbolt.org/g/btHNI9):

```
struct Foo
{
    static auto foo(int bar)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

typedef std::result_of<decltype(Foo::foo)> foo_t;
```

But [this doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/g/IHpqeD):

```
struct Foo
{
    static auto foo(int bar)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    typedef std::result_of<decltype(Foo::foo)> foo_t;
};
```

GCC says "error: use of 'static auto Foo::foo(int)' before deduction of 'auto'", Clang says "function 'foo' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined". Why?

Comment: I think you wanted to write `std::result_of<decltype(&foo)(int)>::type` isn't it?

Comment: @O'Neil There's a fair chance, I have visibly no idea how that works...

Comment: This is the subject of [CWG2335](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2335).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While the way you have written the code makes it appear possible, the in-class definition of `foo()` can only be processed after the class is fully defined.  It is as if you wrote this:

```
struct Foo
{
    static auto foo(int bar);

    typedef std::result_of<decltype(Foo::foo)> foo_t;
};

auto Foo::foo(int bar)
{
    return 0;
}
```

The definition of `foo()` is allowed to use types defined in `class Foo`, including `foo_t`, which would be circular.  Therefore, the definition of `class Foo` is not allowed to use the definition of its member functions--only their declarations.

In other words, you assume the code is fully evaluated from the top to the bottom.  It is not.

Comment: This is correct for all I know, but "you assume the code is fully evaluated from the top to the bottom" is a bit of an unfair statement.